# next() don't notify subscribe()

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have some service

```
isDocAdd: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

addDocument(header) {
        return this.http.post(this.addHl7DocumentUrl, header)
            .map((response: any) => { if (response.status === '404') {
                    this.isDocAdd.next(true);
                }
                else {
                    this.isDocAdd.next(false);
                }
                return response;
            })
            .catch((error: Error) => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
                return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
            });
    }
```

and In component.ts subscribe() notification

```
subscription: Subscription;
message;

constructor(private documentService: DocumentService) {
    this.subscription = this.documentService.isDocAdd.subscribe(val => { this.message = val; });

}
```

In method addDocument() this.isDocAdd.next(val) is set but don't notify component about changes and subscribe() method does not execute.

Comment: This may be a long shot, but I'd check to see if your service get's instantiated more than once (for example if it's being provided by 2 modules). I'd plant a console.log in the constructor of the service and see how many times it gets called.

Comment: @Amit I use console.log() in constructor and this service is called 2 times

Comment: Sounds like I might be right. Check whether you're providing the service in more than one modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your component is created **after** your service.

This means, your subject is not known by your component, so you call next while nothing has subscribed.

One solution is to use a `BehaviorSubject` instead :

```
isDocAdd: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>();
```

It works exactly the same, but a `BehaviorSubject` will notify its observers when you instanciate them (even if the value is null, so test that !)

Comment: ... What. Edit that comment to make it in english please ? What is your issue exactly with my solution ?

Comment: I change to BehaviourSubject and in method addDocument() is called this.docAdd.next(true) but nothing is subscribed and later execution go to line return response.

Comment: Still english-ish, but still, I think I got your point. Your issue isn't the type of subject here, your issue is that **you don't call next on every possible case**. In your code, you test if the status is 404 **in a success callback**. But when you receive a 404, it is actually your `catch` that is called. You also return a Promise in your catch, and an Observable in your map. Your code is problematic at first.

Answer (score 1):

```
private isDocAdd= new Subject<boolean>();
isDocAdd$ = this.isDocAdd.asObservable();
addDocument(header) {
        return this.http.post(this.addHl7DocumentUrl, header)
            .map((response: any) => { response.status === '404') {
                    this.isDocAdd.next(true);
                }
                else {
                    this.isDocAdd.next(false);
                }
                return response;
            })
            .catch((error: Error) => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
                return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
            });
    }
```

and in component.ts

```
subscription: Subscription;
message;

constructor(private documentService: DocumentService) {
    this.subscription = this.documentService.isDocAdd$.subscribe(val => { this.message = val; });
}
```

Comment: still subsribe() is not notify

Comment: can you edit your question with import statement on components and service as well?

Answer (score 0):

Need to create an observable from your subject in order to subscribe to it. use `asObservable`

```
isDocAdd: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
onChanged: Observable<boolean> = this.isDocAdd.asObservable();
```

Now subscribe to the `onChanged`

```
this.subscription = this.documentService.onChanged.subscribe(val => { this.message = val; });
```